# changing from tuple to list and vice versa

Tags: python, list

how could i change `[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]` to `['a',1,'c',3,'b',2]` and vice versa?
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Going in the first direction from `[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]` to `['a',1,'c',3,'b',2]` is [flattening a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python).  Taking the accepted answer from there and modifying for this example:

```
>>> L = [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*L))
['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2]
```

This uses [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) which is a nice tool from `itertools` that flattens sequences quite nicely.

Going the opposite way is zipping:

```
>>> L = ['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2]
>>> zip(L[0::2], L[1::2])
[('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
```

`zip` takes two lists and combines list 1's first element with list 2's first element in a tuple, and so on down the lengths of the list.  So in this one, we basically take the even-indexed elements as our first list (`L[0::2]`), and then the odd-indexed elements as our second (`L[1::2]`)

Comment: Don't forget `itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(L)]*2)`. ;-)

Comment: Also, since you already have `itertools` laying around, you can either `izip` or `zip` over `islice` to avoid having to copy the list.

Answer (score 3):

Here it's my take on it (assuming a contains first list and b second):

```
b = []
for i in a:
    b.extend(i)
```

And reverse:

```
c = []
for i in range(0, len(b) - 1, 2):
   c.append((b[i], b[i+1]))
```

Comment: +1, FWIW, your version of the first tends to be faster than mine in my tests and mine faster than yours on the second - http://pastebin.com/SNrsqDmB

Comment: @Daniel: Be wary of premature optimization.

Comment: @Fred beware of cargo cult quoting. Figuring out which way is faster helps to learn the language so you can write it the fast way the first time.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Figuring out [what needs to be optimized](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/816) instead of worrying about what doesn't is how you write it the fast way.

Comment: @Fred Nurk Figuring out what needs to be optimized only needs to be done if it's too slow. It won't be to slow if you write it the right way the first time. Obsessively profiling code and looking at internals is how you figure it out. I'm talking about building general knowledge here, not optimizing a particular program.

Comment: @aaronasterling: I don't see *any* general knowledge about optimization to be gained from micro-optimizing a 6 item list.  I say micro-optimizing because the above is looking at one very specific made-up situation rather than algorithms, clarity (which goes to code generality), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]
flat = [x for p in L for x in p]
assert flat == ['a', 1, 'c', 3, 'b', 2]

it = iter(flat)
L2 = zip(it, it)
assert L2 == L

print "Success"
```

Comment: +1 for `iter(flat)`. This is the most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

There are already plenty of correct answers here, so this is just a reminder ***not*** to use sum() to flatten lists as although it looks like a neat solution **unfortunately the performance is quadratic**

```
In [1]: L=[('a',x) for x in range(10)]

In [2]: timeit sum(L,())
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 us per loop

In [3]: L=[('a',x) for x in range(100)]

In [4]: timeit sum(L,())
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 us per loop

In [5]: L=[('a',x) for x in range(1000)]

In [6]: timeit sum(L,())
100 loops, best of 3: 8.02 ms per loop
```